# How to solve for +C in a power series

Tags: power-series

From what I've been taught, when you convert a function into a power series using an integral, you have to include +C (C is a constant). Do you solve C by plugging in what the center of the power series is?

For example: I have a power series centered at 1. To solve for C, do I plug in x=1 in the power series?

Comment: Generally, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would, as any other integral.